# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BaslikId'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I want to have a relationship on my tables. I take this error when I update db.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BaslikId', table 'BlogSitesi.dbo.Konular'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

My Models :

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}


public class Baslik:BaseModel
{
    public string Ad { get; set; }
    public int KonuAdet { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Konu> Konular { get; set;}
}


public class Konu:BaseModel
{
    public string KonuBaslik { get; set; } 
    public string Icerik { get; set; }
    public int BaslikId { get; set; }

    public virtual Baslik Baslik { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a relation between `Konu` and `Baslik` (1-n Relation).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where does this error happen? Do you want to have an optional relationship?

Comment: when i update database oon package console. i m trying to codefirst prog.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a 0-n relationship between Konu and Baslik:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Konu>()
        .HasOptional(s => s.Baslik)
        .WithMany(g => g.Konu)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.BaslikId);
```

Also, you need to specify your fk as `int?` to make it nullable like the following:

```
public int? BaslikId { get; set; }
```

Comment: oh. ty so much. im trying now .

Comment: its work . ty so much again. so how can i adapt it to Fluent API?. im learning it .

Comment: Glad it helped. The first statement is the fluent api code.

Comment: really really ty so much. Good night ^^

Comment: You're welcome,  if it was the right answer to your question please mark it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think that you have set column property in your database to "NOT NULL" which means that the database will not allow you to insert NULL values to this column. It's basic practice that id column should be set to NOT NULL. Why you want to insert NULL to id column in first place? This will make trouble when you will do joins.

Comment: how can i change it ? i mean i dont wanna touch db. i m making tables on codefirst.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It would be better as a comment, which you will have the rep to do if you successfully edit one more question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah my bad I am sorry this really should be a comment but as you said I was not able to make comment :(